# How to read test data from JSON and CSV in the same Feature

Tags: json, csv, karate, data-driven-tests, data-driven-forms

I have a Feature whereby I need to read the sanity check from a JSON file and the bulk of the testing from a CSV file. I also need to validate the data in an an Amazon S3 bucket

I have the following in the Background:

- form fields read ('json/Sanity.json')
- def Bulk = read ('data/Bulk.csv')

Scenario1: Validate data in json file

Scenario2: Validate data in csv file

The problem I'm having is that even though the data is being read from the CSV file in Scenario2, the validation is from the json file. Disabling "* form fields read" results in a 400

Answer (score 0):

Your question is impossible to make sense of without a full working example, so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

One suggestion is put the data you need in variables so you have better control:

```
* def fieldData = read('json/Sanity.json')
* def bulkData = read('data/Bulk.csv')
```

And then use them where you want and don't mix things up.

```
* form fields fieldData
```